# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to debug the following code. I'm getting the PLS-00103 twice. Once on line 26 and once on line 35. I've tried commenting out the if statements surrounding the raise no data found exception and the raise statement itself. I can't really see where I'm going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE viewingPercentageDif
   (episodeKeyA IN NUMBER, episodeKeyB IN NUMBER)
    IS 
episodeOrderException EXCEPTION;
notConsecutiveException EXCEPTION;

preceedingEpisode NUMBER := 0;
subsequentEpisode NUMBER := 0;
percetageChange NUMBER :=0;

CURSOR episodeCursorA IS SELECT episode.ep_view_figures FROM episode WHERE episode.ep_suragate_pk = episodeKeyA;
CURSOR episodeCursorB IS SELECT episode.ep_view_figures FROM episode WHERE episode.ep_suragate_pk = episodeKeyB;

BEGIN

IF (episodeKeyA > episodeKeyB) THEN
    RAISE episodeOrderException;
END IF;

BEGIN
    OPEN episodeCursorA;
    FETCH episodeCursorA INTO preceedingEpisode;
    IF episodeCursorA%NOTFOUND THEN
        RAISE NO_DATA_FOUND;
    END IF;
    CLOSE;-- line 26
END;

BEGIN
    OPEN episodeCursorB;
    FETCH episodeCursorB INTO preceedingEpisode;
    IF episodeCursorA%NOTFOUND THEN
        RAISE NO_DATA_FOUND;
    END IF;
    CLOSE;-- line 35
END; 

-- this algorythm should be used for consective episodes only
-- need last and first episodes also
IF ((episodeKeyA + 1) = episodeKeyB) THEN
    -- check if preceeding episode viewing figure is > or < subsequent episode
    -- if preceeding episode < subequent then there has been an decrease
    IF preceedingEpisode < subsequentEpisode THEN
        percentageChange := subsequentEpisode - preceedingEpisode;
        percentageChange := (percentageChange / subsequentEpisode) * 100;

            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Viewing figures have decreased by: ' || percentageChange || '%');

        -- check for increase
    ELSIF preceedingEpisode > subsequentEpisode THEN
            percentageChange := preceedingEpisode - subsequentEpisode;
            percentageChange := (percetageChange / subsequentEpisode) * 100;

            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Viewing figures have increased by: ' || percentageChange || '%');
    END IF;
ELSE 
RAISE notConsecutiveException;
END IF;

    EXCEPTION 
    WHEN notConsecutiveException THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('These episodes are not consecutive');
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO DATA FOUND');
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20003, 'AN ERROR WAS ENCOUNTERED');

    END viewingPercentageDif;
    /
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the cursor name on your close command:

```
BEGIN
    OPEN episodeCursorB;
    FETCH episodeCursorB INTO preceedingEpisode;
    IF episodeCursorA%NOTFOUND THEN
        RAISE NO_DATA_FOUND;
    END IF;
    CLOSE;-- line 35
END;
```

Should be:

```
BEGIN
    OPEN episodeCursorB;
    FETCH episodeCursorB INTO preceedingEpisode;
    IF episodeCursorA%NOTFOUND THEN
        RAISE NO_DATA_FOUND;
    END IF;
    CLOSE episodeCursorB;
END;
```

Same for the other cursor.  Otherwise, how does Oracle know what cursor you are referring to to close?

See this link for details - [Close Cursor Syntax](http://ss64.com/oraplsql/cursor_fetch_close.html)

Comment: @user1763170 - here on StackOverflow it's considered polite to Accept an answer which provides the solution to your question.  To do so, go to the question (oh, you're already here) and underneath the vote total for the answer you'll notice a little outlined checkmark.  If you click inside this checkmark it will turn green, indicating that the answer has been accepted.  The person who answered get 15 reputation points if you do this.  Those of us who answer a lot of questions *do* take note of whether someone Accepts answers or not.  Share and enjoy.

Comment: Sorry, done now, I will review other questions I've asked to make sure people have been acknowledged properly.